# tkinterのメンバ参照に失敗する

Tags: python, python3, windows, vscode, tkinter

ターミナル上では実行できるのですが、VScode上で実行すると、メンバ参照の際に、エラーが出てしまいます。

#### 確認したこと

- `python -m tkinter` でウィンドウが表示されること(バージョンは、8.6でした)
- ターミナル上で以下のコードで正しく実行できること

  ```
  import tkinter

  root = tkinter.Tk()
  root.mainloop()
  ```
- 同じコードをVScodeで実行すると以下エラーがでること

  ```
  $ C:/Users/kento-hayakawa/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/python.exe c:/Git/cellautomata/cellautomata/tkinter.py
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "cellautomata/tkinter.py", line 4, in <module>
      import tkinter
    File "C:\Git\cellautomata\cellautomata\tkinter.py", line 6, in <module>
      root = tkinter.Tk()
  AttributeError: module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'Tk'
  ```

#### 環境

- Python3.7.2

  ```
  $ which python
  /c/Users/kento-hayakawa/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/python
  ```
- Windows

似たような質問をいくつか探してみたのですが、解決出来ませんでした。。。
お手数をおかけしますが、解決方法を教えていただけると幸いです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 入力・編集している作業中のファイル名が tkinter.py ではないですか？ それならばそれを別の名前にしてみましょう。

Comment: 別の名前にしてみたところ、意図通り実行できることを確認しました！
ありがとうございます。とても助かりました。。。

Answer (score 1):

入力・編集している作業中のファイル名が tkinter.py ではないですか？
それならばそれを別の名前にしてみましょう。

---

<sup>この投稿は @kunif さんの[コメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/51749/#comment54023_51749)などを元に編集し、[コミュニティWiki](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1583)として投稿しました。</sup>